# MYSQL/PHP: How do you Order By Starting point in a string?

Tags: php, sql

```
 SELECT
      SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS posts.*,
      CASE
        WHEN postmeta.meta_value REGEXP '$regex'
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END AS keyword_in_title,

      MATCH ( posts.post_content )
        AGAINST ( '".addslashes( $s )."' ) AS mysql_score
    FROM
      $wpdb->posts as posts,
      $wpdb->postmeta as postmeta
    WHERE
      posts.post_date_gmt <= now()
      AND postmeta.post_id = posts.ID
      AND postmeta.meta_key='_headspace_page_title'
      AND posts.post_password = ''
      AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
      AND posts.post_type != 'attachment'
      AND ( postmeta.meta_value REGEXP '$regex'
        OR posts.post_content REGEXP '$regex')
    GROUP BY
      posts.ID
    ORDER BY
      charindex($s, 'keyword_in_title') DESC
    LIMIT 
      $offset, 
      $limit
```

Comment: You substring the column, so the result starts with the letter/position you want sorting to start at.  Your title says mysql, but CHARINDEX is TSQL/SQL Server...

Comment: `addslashes` is not suitable to sanitize strings to be used in MySQL; use `mysql_real_escape_string` or prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

As to the order issue (Apart from the escaping issue @Gumbo pointed out in the comment), `CHARINDEX` is not a [valid mysql string function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).  The [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function looks to be identical (at least from a cursory glance between the docs on SQLServer and MySQL)...

```
$s = mysql_real_escape_string($s);
$order = 'ORDER BY LOCATE(\''.$s.'\', `keyword_in_title`) DESC';
```

Comment: Ohh, now I see what you're doing...  I've changed the code...  And if that doesn't work, can you please provide an example of `$s`?

Comment: something happened, but it definitely didn't sort by first occurrence of a word. $s is the keyword a user is searching for.

Comment: Are you 100% sure?  You could always try running it in PHPMyAdmin (or the like) and experimenting with different settings...  But this is how you do it...  You may (actually you do) want to change `keyword_in_title` to a more meaningful column (perhaps `post_content`)...  Right now, it's sorting by the column that's either a 0 or a 1...  So perhaps changing it to `ORDER BY LOCATE(\''.$s.'\', `post_content`) DESC` which will order by the content string.  (or whatever column you want to order it by)...

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that the code above does not work and hence you're asking a question.

Try adding `charindex($s, 'keyword_in_title') AS cOrder` in your `SELECT` clause and then `ORDER BY cOrder DESC`

Good luck!

Comment: First, there's no `CHARINDEX` MySQL function.  Second, there's no need to select a column in order to sort by it...

Comment: Hey, no need to -1 me, original question asked for function charindex() function. I simply suggested computing it during selection and not just for sorting. No error was provided in the post.